# Listen to internet availability in service in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I already create receiver to test network availability so I can receive when the android has or no network, but how can we listen to internet availability?

The goal. When log in fails (means no internet connection) we have to resend our log in data in Thread in service background task )

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :

```
 ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 if( conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting())
 {
       // your stuff
 }
```

Remeber to put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```